# Random Sentences generator program

Tags: c++

Im having trouble adding a period at the end of a sentence. The program is meant to create 20 sentences with words that I added with the first letter being capitalized and ending in a period. I was able to get the sentences and capitization but not the period. Do i need an if and while statement for that?

```
const char* article[] =
{ "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" };
int articleCount = sizeof(article) / sizeof(char*);

const char* noun[] =
{ "desk", "chair", "envelope", "car", "train", "bus", "boat",
  "elephant", "dog", "cat", "moose", "rabbit"
};
int nounCount = sizeof(noun) / sizeof(char*);

const char* verb[] =
{ "ran", "jumped", "walked", "sprinted", "skipped"
};
int verbCount = sizeof(verb) / sizeof(char*);

const char* adjective[] =
{ "brave", "yellow", "fast", "faithful", "fit"
};
int adjectiveCount = sizeof(adjective) / sizeof(char*);

const char* preposition[] =
{ "the", "to", "from", "across", "outside"
};
int prepositionCount = sizeof(preposition) / sizeof(char*);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));    

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)     
    
    {
        string sentence;       
        int selection;
        selection = rand() % articleCount; 
        sentence = article[selection];   
        sentence += " ";              
        
        selection = rand() % adjectiveCount;  
        sentence += adjective[selection];   
        sentence += " ";               

        selection = rand() % nounCount;
        sentence += noun[selection];    
        sentence += " ";               

        selection = rand() % verbCount;  
        sentence += verb[selection];   
        sentence += " ";               

        selection = rand() % prepositionCount; 
        sentence += preposition[selection];   
        sentence += " ";               

        selection = rand() % articleCount; 
        sentence += article[selection];   
        sentence += " ";              

        selection = rand() % adjectiveCount; 
        sentence += adjective[selection];   
        sentence += " ";               

        selection = rand() % nounCount;  
        sentence += noun[selection];    
        sentence += " ";               

        sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]);     
        cout << sentence << endl;               
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: `sentence += ".";` should do it, no?

Comment: It might be tough to see, but don't your sentences currently end with a space? If you step through your code to see where that space comes from, you should be able to change it to a period, right?

Comment: Free tip: when testing the value of strings, never output the string by itself. Always use some sort of delimiter (pipe characters are often handy) so you have a better chance of noticing "invisible" characters. In this case, try replacing `cout << sentence << endl;` with `cout << '|' << sentence << '|' << endl;` -- notice anything significant?

Answer (score 0):

You should have added a "." instead of a " " at the end of the sentence.
This is how I do it using a more modern C++ style of coding.

```
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// this is the C++ way of initializing a random generator
std::random_device rd{};                    // seed generator
std::default_random_engine random{ rd() };  // random with seed

// std::array has the nice property that you don't have to calculate your size manually (with sizeof). 
const std::array adjectives = { "brave", "yellow", "fast", "faithful", "fit" };
const std::array articles = { "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" };
const std::array nouns = { "desk", "chair", "envelope", "car", "train", "bus", "boat",  "elephant", "dog", "cat", "moose", "rabbit" };
const std::array prepositions = { "the", "to", "from", "across", "outside" };
const std::array verbs = { "ran", "jumped", "walked", "sprinted", "skipped" };

int main()
{
    // for each of the collections of string determine a distribution from 0..N (N is inclusive, so we must do -1)
    // uniform int will make sure the distribution is even over all the numbers.
    // Note that rand() % N for small ints will not be a completely even distribution
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> adjective_selection(0, adjectives.size() - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> article_selection(0, articles.size() - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> noun_selection(0, nouns.size() - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> proposition_selection(0, prepositions.size() - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> verb_selection(0, verbs.size() - 1);


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // a string stream is more efficient for building larger strings
        // then adding strings up
        std::ostringstream sentence;

        // capitalize letter of first word
        std::string first_word{ articles[article_selection(random)] };
        first_word[0] = std::toupper(first_word[0]);
        sentence << first_word << " ";

        // stream all other words to sentence 
        sentence << adjectives[adjective_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << nouns[noun_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << verbs[verb_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << prepositions[proposition_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << articles[article_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << adjectives[adjective_selection(random)] << " ";
        sentence << nouns[noun_selection(random)] << ".";  // <== note the .

        std::cout << sentence.str() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a cleaner more simple way. I did note the "." I think thats where I was messing up. Thanks!